# Differences between jar and war when deploying spring applications

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deployment

I know that one can either deploy spring application as war in a container or run it as a standalone jar.

What I failed to find out are the following:

- what consumes less memory: to run jar file using Tomcat embedded, to run jar file using Jetty embedded or to have it deployed as a war in Tomcat's container?
- what will have a better performance ?
- Any drawbacks not mentioned in Spring documentation when one picks a method or another that we should be aware?

Regards.

Comment: Actually I think there are more aspects to consider: ease of setup and configuration, features. Also, I would add Undertow to this list as I think it is the one with the smalles memory footprint.

Comment: @R4J The points you cited are very interesting to add to discussion. I'd love to hear about them too.